# Algolia: Filter Index by string array attribute with a string array of possible values

Tags: algolia

I have an Algolia Index that contains objects like this:

```
 id: 2,
 name: test,
 important: ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
```

I want to retrieve all entries that e.g. contain either `"dolor"` or `"sit"`.

How would I go about this?

Note: This is just an example, the `important`array of each entry would normally contain around 1 to 4 values (in total around 1.000 possible values). The array to filter it by / to search for could have anywhere between 1 to 400 values.

---

What AFAIK doesn't work:

- searching in Facet Values by using a facetQuery: facetQuery does not allow for boolean operators. Therefore I can only search for only one of `"dolor"` or `"sit"` at once, see [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/faceting/?language=javascript#searching-in-facet-values).
- The [filters docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/?language=javascript#basic-filtering) however says

> Non-numeric attributes (e.g. strings) need to be set up as categories, which we call facets.

So I am wondering if this is possible at all...? Or maybe I am approaching this issue the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the right place and need to combine attributesForFaceting and filters:

- set the `important` attribute as an [attributesForFaceting](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/faceting/#declaring-attributes-for-faceting) either via API or the Dashboard

  - then use the [filters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/?language=instantsearchjs#filter-by-an-array-of-values) to filter on your desired values

Your filter will look like this: `{ "filters": "important:dolor OR important:sit" }`